# Get names of some sub-folders of a directory in a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to delete unnecessary profiles from a public computer. But I also want to retain some profiles like admin and all those which are used in last 10 days.

To delete the profiles I have a batch script. It contains a variable in which if I specify the names of profiles, then those profiles are not deleted.

But I want something which will automatically create that variable.
The format of variable is like

```
set profileName="admin,guest1,guest2"
```

I thought of finding all the profile names using

```
cd C:\Users
for /d %d in (*.*) do set list=%d
```

then check each folder if it contain any file which is in modified less than 10 days using

```
FOR /F "token=" %i IN ('forfiles /P "C:\Users" /S /D -10  ^| find /c /v ""') DO set today=%i
```

then concatenating all those profiles which return above command greater than zero into one variable and also those which I never want to delete.

But I am not able to put all this into one piece.

Please help.

Comment: This seems fraught with hazard. A number of apps will create a "user" which is designed to administer the package, run services, etc.  How about Oracle? I am not sure that just because there is not a recent file under the user home directory that it means the account has not been used or is not needed.

Comment: @Paul : Yes, you are right. I did not thought about that. Basically I just want to delete profiles of users who have not logged in for say 10 days.

Comment: There is probably a better way to determine the most recent login of a user through WMI. Still, I am not sure that is any guarantee that a service account would not be identified for deletion.

Comment: @Paul :  I know there might be better ways, but I need to do it using batch only.